# jquery animate not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

the first time this red div is clicked on, it animates all the way from the top of the page; I would expect it to only go down 50 pixels (as is in fact *does* on subsequent clicks. What is going wrong here?

I've not really used `animate` before. Do I need to somehow specify a start point?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.obscure').on('click', function() {

        var blueDiv = $('.blue').clone();

        blueDiv.css({'display': 'none', 'z-index': '0', 'top' : y, 'position' : 'absolute'});

        $('#wrapper').append(blueDiv);
        var obscure = $('.obscure');
        var offset = obscure.offset();
        var y = offset.top;
        blueDiv.css('top', y);
        blueDiv.show();

        //$('.obscure').css('z-index', 10000);
        var off = parseInt(y) + 50;
        console.log(y);
        $('.obscure').animate({
            top : y + 50
        }, 100);


    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/U7tAV/2/

Comment: Don't understand the problem. Where exactly do you want the red bar to begin? It is located directly under the yellow bar on load.

Comment: @Coby right. and when you click the red bar, it jumps to the top of the page, then slides down. rather than simply sliding down for its original start position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to happen in Firefox, but does in Chrome.

**Fix:** http://jsfiddle.net/U7tAV/10/

I simply changed:

```
    $('.obscure').animate({
        top : y + 50
    }, 100);
```

to apply the `top` position before the animation `.css('top', y)`:

```
    $('.obscure').css('top', y).animate({
        top : y + 50
    }, 100);
```

Comment: yeah, the was the fix I found too. Just wanted to see if it wasn't too hacky! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set position of obscure. If you slow the animation down you see it go to the top then animate down to where it should be. I added

```
obscure.css('top',offset.top);
```

and it worked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.obscure').on('click', function() {

        var blueDiv = $('.blue').clone();

        blueDiv.css({'display': 'none', 'z-index': '0', 'top' : y, 'position' : 'absolute'});

        $('#wrapper').append(blueDiv);
        var obscure = $('.obscure');
        var offset = obscure.offset();
        var y = offset.top;
        blueDiv.css('top', y);
        blueDiv.show();
        obscure.css('top',offset.top); // ADDED THIS

        //$('.obscure').css('z-index', 10000);
        var off = parseInt(y) + 50;
        console.log(y);
        $('.obscure').animate({
            top : y + 50
        }, 100);


    });
});​
```

Not exactly sure but it does work. http://jsfiddle.net/U7tAV/13/